# How do I interpret non-linear meta-analysis regression polynomials?

Tags: regression, non-linear, meta-analysis

I want to know how to interpret output from a meta-analytical model with a categorical fixed factor. The model is quadratic.

I have ran the following meta-analytical regression model

`rma.mv(es, V,  mod= ~poly(c_treattemp, degree=2, raw=TRUE) * Life.stage.of.animal, random= list(~ 1|study_code,  ~1|obs), data= ls_data, method= "REML")`

Life.stage.of.animal is a categorical fixed factor with two levels: Adults and  Immature.

c_treattemp is a continuous fixed effect.

The output of my model is given below.

[image: Model summary]

Looking at the last raw of my output, could you say that there was a significant difference between the quadratic response to temperature between Adults and Immature individuals with a p-value of <0.0001?

What other conclusions can I draw from this output?